# Issue with headers using fsockopen for ESMTP connection on php

Tags: php, smtp

I send email without a problem but when i look on the headers i can see that before of the ones i create appears "X-Mailbox-Line: " and i have no idea why, does any one knows why ?

An example:

```
X-Mailbox-Line: From : <contacto@nidida.com>
Reply-To: <contacto@nidida.com>
MIME-Version:  1.0
```

Comment: Looks like something either the outgoing server, a spam filter, a virus scanner or the receiving server might add. If it is not causing a problem, I wouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the X-* headers add added by receiver SMTP, so your code it's not the problem!